# Why isn't my dictionary printing correctly?

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know why, but the dict at the end of this function won't print fully.  It will only print up to four keys+values and they're only the first four.  Curiously, the 3rd and 4th come out in opposite spots.

`genelist = ['ABC', 'abc', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'ABc', 'abC', 'AbC', 'aBc']`

```
def recombAB(x):

    rec_total = 0
    primlistAB = []
    for item in x:
        split = list(item)
        del split[2]
        primlistAB = primlistAB + split

    listAB = [primlistAB[0] + primlistAB[1], primlistAB[2] + primlistAB[3], primlistAB[4] + primlistAB[5], primlistAB[6] + primlistAB[7], primlistAB[8] + primlistAB[9], primlistAB[10] + primlistAB[11], primlistAB[12] + primlistAB[13], primlistAB[14] + primlistAB[15]]

    print(listAB)

    dictAB = {listAB[0] : freq1, listAB[1] : freq2, listAB[2] : freq3, listAB[3] : freq4, listAB[4] : freq5, listAB[5] : freq6, listAB[6] : freq7, listAB[7] : freq8}


    print(dictAB)
```

`recombAB(genelist)`

This gives me listAB = ['AB', 'ab', 'Ab', 'aB', 'AB', 'ab', 'Ab', 'aB']

And dictAB = {'AB': 9, 'ab': 9, 'aB': 1, 'Ab': 1}

When what I'm looking for is {'AB':479, 'ab':473, 'Ab':15, 'aB':13, 'AB':9, 'ab':9, 'Ab':1, 'aB': 1 }

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suspect your dictionary *is* printing correctly, and you've given it duplicate keys.  (Also, that you refer to "opposite spots" makes it sound like you think dictionaries are ordered.)  Could you modify your code to be a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) or at least show us what `print(listAB)` and `print(dictAB)` return?

Comment: In editing what I had for you, I realized that it is because there are repeats.  Is there any way to keep all of the values and assignments even for repeats?  Also, I didn't realize dictionaries were unordered; I'm brand new to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code partly, by calling the function with `genelist` as its parameter, I get the following output for `listAB`:

```
['AB', 'ab', 'Ab', 'aB', 'AB', 'ab', 'Ab', 'aB']
```

If you look closely, you have duplicate values in there, and essentially just 4 different values.

So when you build your dictionary, you assign multiple values to the same keys, overwriting the previous value.

> When what I'm looking for is `{'AB':479, 'ab':473, 'Ab':15, 'aB':13, 'AB':9, 'ab':9, 'Ab':1, 'aB': 1 }`

A dictionary is a 1-to-1 map from a key to a value. This means that every key uniquely identifies a single element in the dictionary. But in your desired dictionary output, you would have single keys mapping to multiple different values (e.g. `AB` to `479` and `9`). This is not possible.

If you don’t need the map-property but just want to store pairs of values, you could use a list of tuples instead:

```
[('AB', 479), ('ab', 473), ('Ab', 15), ('aB', 13), ('AB', 9), ('ab', 9), ('Ab', 1), ('aB', 1)]
```

Or if you actually need to be able to lookup values from their “key”, you could make a multi-value dictionary by just mapping to a list of values:

```
{'AB': [479, 9], 'ab': [473, 9], 'Ab': [15, 1], 'aB': [13, 1]}
```

Comment: In editing my question up there for DSM, I realized that is the problem. Is there a way to print out every value separately, even if they're repeats?

Comment: You’re welcome! Please remember to upvote helpful answers, and accept the one that solved your problem—this also applies to the other questions you asked. See also [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).